# Is there a JAXB Plugin which generates Builders?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb2, jaxb2-maven-plugin

Are you aware of any good JAXB Plugin which generated Builder pattern classes for the generated JAXB classes? Composing domain using JAXB generated classes is really nasty. 
I saw a plugin someone wrote back in 2010 but it doesn't use the newest maven plugin jaxb2-maven-plugin, and it also requires you to specify bindings for each schema type which is not robust.

Comment: Did you mean's generate the ObjectFactory class?

Comment: If `jaxb-fluent-api` could be somehow configured with `cxf-xjc-plugin` then it might make for a great solution but I'm not sure if that's even possible. Other than that it sounds like you may have already stumbled upon retepTools here: http://blog.retep.org/2010/05/18/implementing-builders-with-jaxb-generated-objects/2/

Comment: This plugin generates immutable classes and optionally builders -
 https://github.com/sabomichal/immutable-xjc

Answer (score 12):

Yes, there is now a plugin to generate fluent builders for JAXB-generated classes.
There is a github project on

https://github.com/mklemm/jaxb2-rich-contract-plugin

It contains a couple of useful JAXB plugins.
You can download source and binaries from github,
or get maven artifacts from [The Central Repository](http://central.sonatype.org/)

Hope this helps. If you have any questions, just ask me, I'm the one who started it.

Comment: Can I use the plugin to generate builders when generating classes from dtd ?

Comment: Though no one seems to have tried yet, I would assume that it will NOT work with a DTD.

Answer (score 6):

The following snippet from a `pom.xml` file, uses maven `cxf-xjc-plugin` to generate the JAXB classes and also leverages `jaxb-fluent-api` to tack-on [fluent interfaces](http://code.google.com/p/jaxb-fluent-api-ext/wiki/Introduction) ... which aren't exactly a complete builder pattern on their own ... but I think they leave room for folks to make decent headway in that direction.

```
        <!-- Used to generate source code based on XSD (schema) file -->
        <!-- http://cxf.apache.org/cxf-xjc-plugin.html -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <extensions>
                    <extension>net.java.dev.jaxb2-commons:jaxb-fluent-api:2.1.8</extension>
                </extensions>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-xsd-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/cxf-xjc/</sourceRoot>
                        <xsdOptions>
                            <xsdOption>
                                <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl/your.xsd</xsd>
                                <packagename>com.your.package.name</packagename>
                                <extensionArgs>
                                    <extensionArg>-Xfluent-api</extensionArg>
                                </extensionArgs>
                            </xsdOption>
                        </xsdOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```