# Can I make JAXB setters return "this", so that they are chainable?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am generating the Java from XML.  The setters all return void.  If they returned "this", then they could be called in a chain.  Is there a way ( an easy way ) to make it generate setters that "return this;" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [JAXB Fluent API Plugin](https://java.net/projects/jaxb2-commons/pages/Fluent-api).

```
 USAddress address = new USAddress()
            .withName(name)
            .withStreet(street)
            .withCity(city)
            .withState(state)
            .withZip(new BigDecimal(zip));
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are talking about is the builder pattern. If you are interested in generating classes from XML that have the additional setter methods returning this for chaining, take a look at the following post: [Is there a JAXB Plugin which generates Builders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489211/is-there-a-jaxb-plugin-which-generates-builders)